# ASP.NET: Why Localize strings?

Tags: asp.net, localization

I'm just getting started using Resharper with VS-2008, and one of the 'errors' it gave me was to localize a Label's text in the code-behind. I've worked with Localization before to Localize a website from english into french, but I don't understand what the benefit is to localizing beside that usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's an internal application that you're not going to be distributing, there's not much of a benefit to it. It may be handy to collect all your strings in one central location for easy maintenance later, but only you know whether that's worth the effort on your specific project.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit like asking what the benefit of addition is beyond adding two numbers together.

Localization is generally about presenting the most relevant user experience to each user with minimal code changes - giving each user a "skin" using their language and regional settings (e.g. for things like formatting numbers appropriately).

Granted very many web sites *aren't* localized at all, but R# is prompting you do give your users the best possible experience :)

Comment: Formatting numbers is Internationalization actually. Localization is a process of adapting software to local market and it consists of translating messages, modifying graphics, colors and layouts.

Comment: @Pawel: True... although in my experience various different organizations use the terms "localization", "internationalization" and "globalization" to mean different things :(